# Conditional Active Record Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, conditional-statements

The following [geocodes](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) (gets the coordinates of the address) automagically when I create or update. This is in my Location model

```
def full_address
    full_address = "#{address},#{city},#{state}"
end

geocoded_by :full_address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

But I don't want the geocoding done if I set `coords_locked` to true.

I can't figure out how to do this. I tried

```
geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => { :coords_locked == false || :address_changed?  }
```

What is the correct syntax or am I going about this all wrong. Thank you

PS. Just realized I probably don't need the `full_address =`.

Comment: Also if you are trying do what you were asking this syntax would work:  after_validation :geocode, :if => !coords_locked || :address_changed?

Comment: I get myself tangled up in double negatives, but if :coords_locked is false I do want the coordinates set. If `coords_locked` is `true` that means I don't want changes made.

But more importantly if the syntax `!coords_locked` without a colon works great, because I think I tried with a `!:` and got an error. I'll try this out and get back.

Comment: `after_validation :geocode, :if => !:coords_locked && :address_changed? ` results in the following whether `:coords_locked` is `true` or `false`

    undefined method `after_validation' for false:FalseClass            
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @location.update(location_params)
            # If update succeeds, redirect to the show page
            format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @location }

which is stock controller language.

Comment: The ! negative doesn't work, so for testing I tried `after_validation :geocode, :if => :coords_locked? && :address_changed?` and ran without errors. Except it changed the coordinates whether or not `coords_locked` was `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following from the Rails Guides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

#### 5.3 Using a Proc with :if and :unless

Finally, it's possible to associate :if and :unless with a Proc object which will be called. Using a Proc object gives you the ability to write an inline condition instead of a separate method. This option is best suited for one-liners.

So perhaps something like this:

```
  after_validation :geocode,
    if: Proc.new { |location| location.coords_locked? && location.address_changed? }
```

Then you could maybe setup some scopes to define `coords_locked?` and `address_changed?`

Comment: I'll have to get my head around Procs. I'm struggling with Callbacks. Hope to get there. Thanks, I'll look again at Procs.